# php-amqplib loop while there are messages only

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

There is a [demo](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/amqp_consumer.php) consumer:

It loops as long as the channel has callbacks registered

```
while (count($ch->callbacks)) {
  $ch->wait();
}
```

The thing is that I need to get not more than 100 messages from the queue for example. If there are only 80 for example it should return just 80 and exit loop.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to get 100 messages, then don't cancel the callback until you process all the messages

Comment: Can you give me some direction to research on this? How this should look like?

Comment: Don't issue a basic_cancel like here: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/amqp_consumer.php#L53 also see: http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Comment: When you do a queue_declare you can obtain how many messages are in the queue, then set your consumer to exit after that many messages have been consumed

Answer (score 0):

Would the following code work for you ?

```
$callbacks = count($ch->callbacks);

for ($i = 0, $count = $callbacks < 100 ? $callbacks : 100; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $ch->wait();
}
```

Comment: This didn't work

    $callbacks = count($ch->callbacks);
    var_dump($callbacks);

    int(1)

While I have 9 messages in the queue

So it returns only 1 message. And actually I would like to have some way to break the loop while inside the loop, not limiting it before starting the loop, and we might have other consumers get messages since this loop was started.